# AsyncContext in Servlet 3.0 infinite browser loading

Tags: java, html, servlets

I'm going to make streaming. I have .jsp file and at the end of .jsp file I include my Async Servlet using following code:

```
<jsp:include page = '/simple' flush = 'true' />
```

So I want when whole page is loaded to open an infinite Async request, which will handle Async response.

Here is my Servlet code:

```
public class SimpleAsyncServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public static AsyncContext ctx;
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        req.setAttribute("org.apache.catalina.ASYNC_SUPPORTED", true);
        ctx = req.startAsync();
        ctx.setTimeout(0);
    }
}
```

From other java classes I'm using the static SimpleAsyncServlet.ctx.getResponse.getWriter() to println some javascript code to current page. It is working without any problem, but browser keep showing that it's loading. According to Async idea page should be loaded and this Async Request should stay alive in background and..that's it, but no....browser keeps loading the page till forever (timeout is 0, cos I want to have infinite open reqeust)

Where am I wrong and how can I make this permanent request without this browser loading ?

P.S. I have tried to access my servlet direct from url (localhost.../simple) and then I see nothing printed on page. It keep loading till forever.

Comment: I have corrent it. It is flush = 'true'. I have:

    @javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet( // servlet name
    name = "simple",
    // servlet url pattern
    value = {"/simple"},
    // async support needed
    asyncSupported = true);

and also I've tried req.startAsync(req, res);

Nothing helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to achieve the impossible.

The browser will showing that the page is loading until it knows it has received the full request by one of the following methods:

- it has received the number bytes stated in a Content-Length header
- the connection is closed
- it received an end chunk when using chunked encoding

Since you want an 'infinite' response, none of the three options above is ever going to happen.

Comment: How can I make streaming then? Or how can I implement "push" to the browser? As far as I understand "push" is exactly only infinite open request or I am wrong ?

Comment: And also if I'm making Ajax request from .js as far as I remember I don't see browser loading

Comment: HTTP is a request / response protocol. You can't implement a true push. There are various ways to hack something that looks like a push using HTTP. If you want a true server push then you need something like WebSocket. You can stream content from a Servlet with or without Servlet 3.0 Async. If the browser is displaying the result as a web page then it is always going to look like the page is loading. To avoid that, you need something embedded in the page (pick your technology of choice) that performs the request and processes the response so the browser doesn't realise what is happening.

Comment: Thank you a lot, but can you recommend me some technology. Actually I'm going to make chat.

Comment: I'd go with WebSocket. See http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/tomcat/trunk/webapps/examples/WEB-INF/classes/websocket/chat/ChatWebSocketServlet.java?view=log and http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/tomcat/trunk/webapps/examples/websocket/chat.html?view=log for a simple chat example.

Comment: Instead of Java asynchronous I used Ajax to servlets and threads to control chat. Now it's working, thank you for advices.